# show a string from backend-server as icon

Tags: html, angular, typescript, icons

I get a response from backend server for my angular 2/4 application. The response includes an attribute "connectionStatus", which indicates the status of a database-connection with "UP" or "DOWN". I show the retrieved status and other informations in my view with the following code:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor='let database of environment.databases'>
        <td>{{database.connectionName}}</td>
        <td>{{database.dbSourceType}}</td>
        <td>{{database.username}}</td>
        <td>{{database.password}}</td>
        <td>{{database.connectionUrl}}</td>
        <td>{{database.creationDate}}</td>
        <td>{{database.connectionStatus}}</td>
        <td>
            <button (click)='onEditDatabase(environment,database)'class="btn btn-primary btn-sm oi oi-cog"></button>
            <button (click)='onDeleteDatabase(database)'class="btn btn-danger btn-sm oi oi-trash"></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Instead of showing the status as "UP" or "DOWN", i want to use [openiconics](https://useiconic.com/open/). If the state is "UP", then use the `check`-icon, if its down, the `flash`-icon. How can i realize that? i appreciate all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of **ngClass**

```
<td [ngClass]="(database.connectionStatus ==='UP')?'upclass':'downclass'"></td>
```

**in the css define the class and icons**

```
.upclass{check-icon}


.downclass{flash-icon}
```

Comment: what is the syntax in the curly braces? the icon-classname is `oi oi-check`

Comment: then add that class instead of `upclass` or `downclass`. its is a ternary operator

Comment: thats right, just had to add the classname of the icon, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can use *ngIf or [hidden] to display one of the status as per your condition.

```
<td *ngIf="database.connectionStatus">your icon UP html tag here</td>

<td *ngIf="!database.connectionStatus">your icon DOWN html tag here</td>
```

Comment: after i posted the question, i had the same idea with `ngIf` and it worked, but Rahul Singh's approach is much better, with `ngIf`i have 6 lines of code, with `ngClass` only one line. I still thank you for your help =)